# Is there a way to not be shown in the list of potential users in Trello?

Tags: trello, username

Is there any way of preventing being listed in the user suggestions list when adding some to a project?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [possibility for the future](https://trello.com/card/board/allow-users-to-specify-how-visible-they-are-to-the-outside/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e723f5eeb752c26d6154caf).